# Shell Script to find string of file A in File B and print Yes or No in front of particular string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have two file A & B. File A contains some strings. I wanted to find strings in file B & if a string is there in file B. Print Yes in front of string in file A otherwise print NO.

Propose any solution.

Comment: basically you would read the content of fileA and search each string of fileA in fileb? and if there is any matching, the script would print something like "YES - string" or "No - string" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r searchPattern; do    
    if grep -q "$searchPattern" fileB; then
        flag="YES"
    else
        flag="NO"    
    fi
    printf "%s %s\n" "$flag" "$searchPattern"
done < fileA >output
```

Comment: You want `read -r` unless you specifically want the shell to parse backslashes and perform other weird legacy behavior in `read`; and redirecting the whole loop once after `done` is going to be a lot more efficient than reopening the file for appending for each input line.  Furthermore, you should take care to quote the search pattern, and generally any variable where you do not specifically require the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I fixed the code.

Comment: I edited another round on top of yours.  I'm not sure if overwriting `fileA` is what the OP really wanted -- if that is so, then parts of my edit will need to be reverted.  Anyhow, maintaining a copy of the output you want in a variable is a bit of a wart; I would simply move `output` back on top of `fileA` at the end if that's the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]; next} {if($0 in a){print "YES ",$0}else print "NO ",$0}' B.txt A.txt
```

Above awk will compare entire line.

Comment: So far, the other answers here deserve a downvote more than this one.  Upvoted to compensate.  You should probably explain how this works, though.

Comment: @tripleee i downvoted and i think it is warranted. This answer does not check if a string is on a line. It checks if the line from one file directly matches a line from another. I don't know if this is what OP actually wants though because the question sucks and i also downvoted that. Also if you think the other answers deserve a downvote more, then downvote them.

Comment: @123 Hmm, the question is poorly specified on this point, but I guess you might be right.  Still, this approach is basically how I would do it. You could build up a big honkin' regex in `FNR==NR` and have the rest of the code pretty much as it is, in order to do a single pass over both input files. ... I certainly did downvote the other two, with comments.

Comment: @tripleee yes you could, and if the answer had that then i would probably have upvoted. Regarding `with comments` I don't normally comment on answers i downvote unless asked as people tend to hold grudges.

Answer (score -1):

this is an option

```
#!/bin/ksh
fileA=$1
fileB=$2

#add check to verify if both file are really passed by parameter

for line in $(cat $fileA)
do
   check=$(grep $line $fileB)
   if [ -z "${check}" ];then
        echo "NO-$line"

   else
        echo "YES-$line"

   fi
done > fileNew
```

this is the output of fileNew

```
`YES-string1                                                                                                                                                                                               
 YES-string2                                                                                                                                                                                               
 YES-string3                                                                                                                                                                                               
 NO-string4                                                                                                                                                                                                
 YES-string5                                                                                                                                                                                               
 NO-string6                                                                                                                                                                                                
 YES-string7                                                                                                                                                                                               
 NO-string8 `
```

you can add i.e.

```
mv fileNew $fileA
```

at the end of the script if you need to replace the fileA

Regards

C

p.s.
that are the input files

```
bash-4.3$ cat fileA.txt                                                                                                                                                                                   
string1                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string2                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string3                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string4                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string5                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string6                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string7                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string8                                                                                                                                                                                                   
bash-4.3$ cat fileB.txt                                                                                                                                                                                   
string2                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string2                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string1                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string3                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string5                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string2                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string7                                                                                                                                                                                                   
string9
```

Comment: The exit code from `grep` tells you whether there was a match or not. [Don't read lines with `for`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)  Quote your variables.  Even with those things fixed, this is a painfully inefficient way to reimplement `grep -f` just for customizing the output format.